# netcat/socat as http intercept proxy

Tags: linux, http-proxy, socat

i've heard that socat/netcat can be used as a proxy server which have an ability to redirect to another proxy server.

but in my situation i want to "tricking" it a little bit with some http header manipulation.

so my goal is using netcat/socat to act as localhost "http CONNECT" proxy server that has an ability to read & rebuild the http request by the client then redirect it to external squid proxy server.

after searching around for hours, i couldn't find any example how can i achive this.

is it even possible ? if yes, then how? since i new to netcat/socat thing.

Thank you.